# Formatting 3 column array in Google Sheets with unique counts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the following data and the work-in-progress formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA({unique(A2:A);flatten(UNIQUE(filter(C2:C, A2:A=A2))&": "&countif(filter(C2:C, A2:A=A2),UNIQUE(filter(C2:C, A2:A=A2))))})`

How can I go about creating the DESIRED OUTPUT from the dataset?

[image]

Google Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-ZRe0hgFWdb318xHtiIGmR-RvxSgv518k9wCUBfCm0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query()` function lets you get those results, although they will be tabulated in a format that is different from what you requested:

`=query(A1:C, "select A, count(A) where C is not null group by A pivot C", 1)`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, y, 
 QUERY(FLATTEN({SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER({IFERROR(x/0, "​"), x}, x<>""))), 
 IF(QUERY(y, "offset 1", )="",,INDEX(y, 1)&": "&QUERY(y, "offset 1", ))}), 
 "where Col1 is not null offset 1", ))
 (A2:A, QUERY(A2:C, "select count(A) where C is not null group by A pivot C")))
```

[image]